# CSS/JS to imitate multiple mobile app screens: left-to-right orientation, one-at-a-time behavior

Tags: css, mobile, vue.js, flexbox, mobile-browser

I am working on a Flask / Vue.js web app that I want to have work well with both laptop and mobile browsers. The layout I've chosen is to have a series of mobile-screen-shaped areas that are oriented in a left-to-right fashion when viewed on a laptop browser. Currently when viewed on mobile those mobile-screen-sized areas get shifted into a top-to-bottom orientation, and the user can scroll the screen up and down to go through them all.

What I'd like to do is to have the mobile CSS instead simulate a mobile app by having those cards(?) oriented left-to-right (like the laptop view), and have a swipe shift each one into view or out of view, but always snapping to a single card at a time, rather than displaying 1/4th of the first card and 3/4ths of the second card (for example).

Current laptop browser view:
[image]

Desired mobile behavior:
[image]

Comment: you can achive this with the media rule on css, read: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: in mobile, you want a [carousel](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/)
right ?

Comment: Genaro, I'm aware of the media rule, but how would I use it?

Comment: kukkuz, yes, thank you, that's what I want.

Comment: Do you need to support IE/Edge? Have you considered [scroll snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap_Points)?

Comment: I wasn't aware of scroll-snap, but it sounds like the kind of thing I'm looking for. It's probably best if I support Edge, and it looks like Safari doesn't support it either. The docs also say "it's in the process of being dropped".

Comment: Not a great support indeed, but I was not aware it is being dropped. Check [this pen](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/JygZRQ), it was the best I could do with scroll snap. It is based on [this](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points) and it uses a [polyfill](https://github.com/ckrack/scrollsnap-polyfill) for better support (but can't say for IE/Edge).